# VIsual Studio 2010 Holding onto WCF service reference Passwords?

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, configuration, passwords

I don't believe this either - I'll show anyone who's interested on Join me!

Here's the deal. Two computers, different behaviour to do with adding a service reference.

Computer 1 - I'll call him BigMac
Computer 2 - I'll call him Littlemac

I wrote a web service on BigMac. And a Windows Client app to call it. All works great. Deployed it to client's computer, all works great. We decide to secure the server so consumers must pass Windows User Name / passwords to the service, and we'll use Https. 8 hours later, and lots of searching on here and elsewhere I got it going. Server config. looks like this:

```
<services>
  <service name="SecureWcfTestsApplication.Service1">
    <endpoint address=""
      binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration ="Binding2"
      contract="SecureWcfTestsApplication.IService1" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="Binding2">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Deploy it on remote server. Go to any web browser, type in the service URL, enter a user name and password and I get the service description. All good.

However - the client code can call it without offering any credentials.

Client code is just this:

remote.Service1Client service1 = new remote.Service1Client();
   service1.GetData(20);

That's it. It runs from within Visual Studio, and as an exe. If I copy the exe to another machine it doesn't run.

Ok  - Start a new project on BigMac (same computer) - there's no service implementation here just a Windows app. I add the remote service reference, and yet again it doesn't ask for the user name and password. And I can call the service without any credentials.

Go to LittleMac. Open web browser and navigate to the service - I need a user name / password. Open Visual Studio, add service reference - I need a user name / password as I expect. And the client code needs to set the user name / password.

I rebooted BigMac - started from scratch - new project - add web reference - no password required and it runs.

Wtf? Anyone?

Best

Ray

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: you have no Windows Domain.

Ok, let's think for a moment at what "Windows" authentication means. From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596521301-02-10.aspx):

> *Windows Authentication*
>
> The service typically uses Kerberos when a Windows Domain Server is available, or NTLM when deployed in a workgroup configuration. The caller provides the service with its Windows credentials (such as a ticket or a token) and the service authenticates that against Windows.

Now, supposing you have no Domain in your network, it means that it is actually performing the authentication against your local account which is running Visual Studio and the client.exe on BigMac. Since your local account is already authenticated (you are logged in), the client just forwards the token to the web service to authenticate itself.

LittleMac on the other hand is authenticated locally on the other machine, which means that it has to provide username and password for a local account on the machine where the web service runs.

I don't know if this is exactly your case and my description may not be 100% true to what is happening in the background, but in any case WCF is not holding onto passwords, so don't worry about that :)

HTH

Comment: Hey there - thanks for having a stab at it. If what you are saying is correct - is there any way to "deauthenticate" this computer as this can actually cause some problems can't it? On this machine I forget to set the credentials in code but it works anyway. But it wouldn't work when deployed, would it?

Comment: I do not know if you are able to avoid the automatic authentication, since WCF does it for you without asking. No, it wouldn't work if you deploy it on a different machine, as you could see for yourself when you deployed it on the other machine.

Comment: On a second thought, you could try setting the ClientCredentialType to "Password" (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733836.aspx), then it should theoretically ask you for your credentials even if you are already authenticated. I'm sorry but I have not the time to try it right now.